# My template responsive menu Bootstrap does not work?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

As you can see in my picture I drew a line on the menu to the menu when I was very little, I got browser menu I was like why not?

I want my menu when the browser is a little like drumbi site to menu

main site : [drumbi](http://www.drumbi.com)

[**Menu**](https://dl.dropbox.com/s/oqgxh1usaszmb8u/3-menu.JPG)

[**My template code**](http://jsfiddle.net/psot98/5ymMe/1/)

Code Menu:

```
<div class="header">
<div class="container">

    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand">
            <img class="img-responsive" style="width: 150px" src="images/websitelogo.png" alt="logo" />
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right nav-menu">

            <li><a href="#">Pricing</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">About </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Help </a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Sign In </a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is great script for a custom walker class which generates the required mark up for bootstrap 3 styling, it allows dividers and glyphicons to be placed in the menu: check it out: https://github.com/Firestorm-Developments/wp-bootstrap-navwalker